# Cannot receive broadcast in activity which has been sent from a service

Tags: android, android-service

In my service I am using the LocalBroadcastManager to send information to an activity, but the activity never received something.

In my service

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("openJobsBroadcast");
    Log.d(TAG, "Broadcasting open jobs count");
    // You can also include some extra data.
    intent.putExtra("openJobs", 5);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In the activity I register the reveiver in the onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.action_activity);
    transfer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.transfer);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new    IntentFilter("openJobsBroadcast"));

}
```

with this receiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String openJobsCount = intent.getStringExtra("openJobs");
        Log.d(TAG, "received new openJobCount from service with value " + openJobsCount);
    }
};
```

The service is defined in the manifest like this

```
<service
        android:name="android.uploader.services.AttachService"
        android:icon="@drawable/loading_icon"
        />
```

Any idea why the onReceive in my activity will never be called?

Thanks